# Prevent old notifications from firing

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

I'm making an app that i schedule notifications for a day say morning , evening and night - the problem is if i opened the app at night the old notifications of morning and evening shows . i use below code

```
    val alarmMgr = MyApplication.appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager?
    val intent = Intent(MyApplication.appContext, MyAlarmReceiver::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("Title",title)
    intent.putExtra("Body",body)
    intent.putExtra("Id",id)
    intent.putExtra("Sound",sound)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyApplication.appContext, id, intent, 0)
    alarmMgr!!.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent)
```

With this part inside `onReceive` of alarm

```
private fun sendNotification( intent: Intent) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val notificationID = intent.extras!!.getInt("Id")!!
            val title = intent.extras!!.getString("Title")
            val body = intent.extras!!.getString("Body")
            val sound = intent.extras!!.getString("Sound")

            val channelID = "com.ebookfrenzy.notifydemo.news"

            val resultIntent = Intent(MyApplication.appContext, MainActivity::class.java)

            resultIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                MyApplication.appContext,
                0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            val notification = Notification.Builder(MyApplication.appContext,
                channelID)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setChannelId(channelID)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build()

             sound?.let {
                 notification.sound =  Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + MyApplication.appContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/$it")
             }

        var notificationManager = MyApplication.appContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager?.notify(notificationID, notification)


    } else {


    }
 }
```

Comment: `time` is the only really relevant thing here, but you've not shown how you're figuring its value. If you're setting times only, you need to account for the possibility that the code is running at a point when those times have already passed for today. When you set an alarm in the past, it fires as soon as possible.

Comment: @MikeM. what if the notification is repeatable so i need to make sure it's added as an alarm but its time passed , i don't need to skip it as user may close the app and leaves it un scheduled